# Why some of the directory in docker container can be mount and share files out and some can not

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I'm a new leaner of docker.I came a cross a problem while I'm trying to make my own docker image.
Here's the thing.I create a new DockerFile to build my own mysql image in which I declared MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD and put some init scripts in the container.
Here is my Docker

```
FROM mysql:5.7
MAINTAINER CarbonFace<553127022@qq.com>
ENV TZ                      Asia/Shanghai
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD     Carbon@mysqlRoot7
ENV INIT_DATA_DIR           /initData/sql
ENV INIT_SQL_FILE_0         privileges.sql
ENV INIT_SQL_FILE_1         carbon_user_sql.sql
ENV INIT_SQL_FILE_2         carbonface_sql.sql
COPY ./my.cnf /etc/mysql/donf.d/
RUN mkdir -p $INIT_DATA_DIR
COPY ./sqlscript/$INIT_SQL_FILE_0 $INIT_DATA_DIR/
COPY ./sqlscript/$INIT_SQL_FILE_1 $INIT_DATA_DIR/
COPY ./sqlscript/$INIT_SQL_FILE_2 $INIT_DATA_DIR/
COPY ./sqlscript/$INIT_SQL_FILE_0 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY ./sqlscript/$INIT_SQL_FILE_1 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY ./sqlscript/$INIT_SQL_FILE_2 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

I'm trying to build a docker image which contains my own config file and when mounted it would be showed in the local directory and can be modified.
I'm really confused that when I start my container with this image like the official description and also here is my commands:

```
docker run -dp 3306:3306 \
-v /usr/local/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql \
-v/usr/local/mysql/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d \
--name mysql mysql:<my builded tag>
```

You know I'm trying to mounted the
`/usr/local/mysql/conf` to the `/etc/mysql/conf.d` in the container which is been told as the custom config file mounted location.
And I supposed that my custom config file `my.cnf` which has been copied into the image during docker build and would be show in my local direcroty `/usr/local/mysql/conf`
And since I already copied my custom config file into image which you can see in my DockerFile.
But it turns out that the directory is empty and the `/etc/mysql/conf.d` is also overwrite by local directory.
Before I run my container, both `/usr/local/mysql/conf` and `/usr/local/mysql/data` is empty at all.
OK fine, I've been told that the volume mounted directory would overwrite the file inside the container.
But how could the empty data directory shows the data files inside the container but the empty conf directory overwrite the conf.d directory in the container.
It make no sense.
I was very confused and I would be very appreciate it if someone can explain why it happens.

My OS is MacOS Big Sur and I used the latest docker.

Answer (score 0):

A host-directory bind mount, `-v /host/path:/container/path`, *always* hides the contents of the image and replaces it with the host directory.  If the host directory is empty, the container directory will be the same empty directory at container startup time.

The Docker Hub `mysql` container has [an involved entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/a09a716a88ce34a17e16df3f8b091066d90e6f34/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh) that checks to see if the data directory is empty, and if so, initializes the database; abstracted out

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# (actually in hundreds of lines of shell code, with more options)
if [ ! -d /var/lib/mysql/data/mysql ]; then
  mysql_install_db
  # (...and start a temporary database server and run the
  # /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d scripts)
fi

# then run the main container command
exec "$@"
```

Simply the presence of a volume doesn't cause files to be copied (with one exception at one specific point in the lifecycle for named volumes), so if you need to copy content from a container to the host you either need to do it manually with `docker cp` or have a way in the container code to do it.

Comment: Obviously I'm a new-bee. I study and read many build script and Dockerfile for the docker image build in the past few weeks. I can understand it now and thank you for explain that to me.